# GCM multiplication ASM

Tags: assembly, x86-64, sse, aes-gcm

I am trying to implement the algorithm of the nist 800-38d [here](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/Legacy/SP/nistspecialpublication800-38d.pdf) section 6.3

I have the following code in asm. I am following the following vector test of an intel paper [here](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.447.379&rep=rep1&type=pdf) page 71. The result of my code is different, I do not know where I can be wrong, someone could help me?

Thanks.

```
.section .text
.globl _start
.align 16

_start:

pxor %xmm0, %xmm0                        # xmm0 | Z
movdqu %xmm1, (%rsp)                     # rsp  | x
movdqu %xmm4, -16(%rsp)                  # rsp  | V

_l02:

movq $-16, %rax                           # byte count

_l01:

xorq %r8, %r8                             # bit count 
movq $-8, %r9

_l0:

btq %r8, 16(%rsp, %rax)                 # check the first bit
jnc _l1                                 # si el bit es 0,  paso a LSB

movdqu -16(%rsp), %xmm3
pxor %xmm3, %xmm0                        # si el bit es 1, Z xor V, paso a LSB

_l1:

btq $63, -8(%rsp)                        # check the 127 bit in V
jc _l2

movq -8(%rsp), %rbx
shlq $63, %rbx
shrq $1, -8(%rsp)
shrq $1, -16(%rsp)                       # LSB (V) = 0
orq %rbx, -16(%rsp)

jmp _l3

_l2:

movq -8(%rsp), %rbx
shlq $63, %rbx
shrq $1, -8(%rsp)                       # LSB (V) = 1
shrq $1, -16(%rsp)
orq %rbx, -16(%rsp)
xorq $0x00000000000000e1, -16(%rsp)

_l3:

incq %r8
incq %r9
js _l0

incq %rax
js _l01

# ret Z in xmm0 register
```

Comment: Before you go trying to implement advanced crypto in assembly, you should probably try to improve your debugging skills.

Comment: Note that `btq %r8, 16(%rsp, %rax)` is very slow; slower than calculating which dword or byte `%r8` would index and doing a `mov` load into a register for `bt %rd8, %ecx` or whatever.  Or if you can just keep a 128-bit value in a pair of registers and add/adc it to shift 1 bit at a time into CF, that's even better.  What's all this memory destination stuff for, anyway?  Have you heard of store-forwarding stalls?  Regardless of correctness, this strategy of updating memory with RMW memory destination instructions and doing `movdqu` loads is bad for performance.  A SIMD reg can do most of that.